# javascript audio fade out

Tags: javascript, html, audio, fadeout

When I press 'Arrow Up' button on keyboard, I want my audio fade out and stop. It seems to fade out, however, it appears again and never stops.

*music.html:48 Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to set the 'volume' property on 'HTMLMediaElement': The volume provided (-0.1) is outside the range [0, 1].*

I am beginner of Javascript.

Here is my code.

**HTML**

```
    <body>

<input type="text" size="3" value="1" id="numtext" style="font-size:500px" >

<audio id=1>
    <source src=BGM/a.mp3>
</audio>

<audio id=2>
    <source src=BGM/b.mp3>
</audio>

<audio id=3>
    <source src=BGM/c.mp3>
</audio>

</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
    <script language="JavaScript">

var interval
var timeout

document.onkeydown = function() {

if(event.keyCode == 38){
        var x = document.getElementById('numtext').value;
            var sounds = document.getElementById(x);

        interval = setInterval(fade, 200);

        return;

        }
}

function fade() {

        var x = document.getElementById('numtext').value;
            var sounds = document.getElementById(x);
        sounds.volume = sounds.volume - 0.1;

        var timer = setTimeout(function() {

        window.clearInterval(interval);
        for(i=0; i<sounds.length; i++) sounds[i].pause(); 
        for(i=0; i<sounds.length; i++) sounds[i].currentTime = 0;

        }, 2000);

        timeout = setTimeout(stopFade, 2000);

}

function stopFade() {
        var x = document.getElementById('numtext').value;
            var sounds = document.getElementById(x);

        for(i=0; i<sounds.length; i++) sounds[i].pause(); 
        for(i=0; i<sounds.length; i++) sounds[i].currentTime = 0;
        sounds.volume = 1;

}

</script>
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fade function needs to check that the volume its assigning is between 0 and 1. Since you're only turning the volume down you can just check if it's greater than 0.

```
var interval
var timeout

document.onkeydown = function() {

    if(event.keyCode == 38){
        interval = setInterval(fade, 200);
    }

}

function fade() {

        var x = document.getElementById('numtext').value;
        var sounds = document.getElementById(x);

        var newVolume = sounds.volume - 0.1;

        // Check if the newVolume is greater than zero
        if(newVolume >= 0){
            sounds.volume = newVolume;
        }
        else{
            // Stop fade
            clearInterval(interval);
            sounds.volume = 0;
            sounds.pause();
            sounds.currentTIme = 0;
        }

}
```

I've trimmed out the unnecessary code here.